# Are there cases where Protocol-Relative URLs is preferred over HTTPS?

Tags: google-analytics, disqus, anti-patterns, protocol-relative

## Protocal-relative URLs

[Protocol-relative URLs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator#Protocol-relative_URLs) are URLs that begin with `//`, instead of `http://` or `https://`. The actual protocol used to load the resource is derived from the containing page; Therefore, `//example.com/smile.jpeg` in an HTTPS page will load `https://example.com/smile.jpeg`.

## Anti-pattern claim

[It has been widely claimed](http://www.paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/) that Protocol-relative URLs should be completely abandoned in favor of HTTPS; one of my recent pull requests was rejected do that claimed (and eventually accepted with HTTPS only).

## The problem

Many reputable services on the web still use Protocol-relative URLs. For example, Google Analytics calls `//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js`, and Disqus [calls](https://disqus.com/admin/universalcode/) `//EXAMPLE.disqus.com/embed.js`.

**Is there a reason why web services still use the insecure Protocol-relative URLs instead of HTTPS?**

Answer (score 2):

Because the services might not be called via HTTP at all? Take a look at the list of [IANA-registered URI schemes](https://www.iana.org/assignments/uri-schemes/uri-schemes.xml). By using a protocol-relative URL it allows the page to be loaded by any scheme that allows the same syntax.

Protocol-relative URLs also allow control of the scheme to be done in the server configuration as opposed to the page-generation code or the page templates. If protocol-relative URLs are used the Web server can be configured to forcibly redirect any plain `http:` request to an `https:` equivalent and typos in the page templates or code can't accidentally use `http:` (or if they do, it's easy to scan the code and template files and find all occurrences of the problem).

Comment: Do you think that's the case with the two aforementioned services?

Comment: Probably for Disqus and especially for Google the rule was put down that code-behind should only say where the resource is, it's the server's job to determine the protocol. With that in place, making a policy change like forcing everything to HTTPS is just a server configuration change, without that it'd involve scanning the entire codebase and touching every place in the code that generated an absolute URL. For Google that could be... a lot of code.

Comment: So, in the case of plain web pages in which I embed GA and Disqus code, is there a reason not to just use https instead of protocol-relative URLs?

Comment: If the asset is available via https, there is no reason to use protocol relative URLs

Answer (score 1):

If the asset is available via https, there is no reason to use protocol relative URLs. Specifying https is inherently more secure than leaving it open-ended, which provides the opportunity for an insecure http to be injected. Performance is not a reason (ref: https://istlsfastyet.com/).

It is only a matter of time that those services you mention will switch to https-only protocols: it's in their best interests to consolidate around a single protocol/URL and to only provide securely delivered assets.